# Python: Issue with string concatenation

Tags: python, printing, pyramid

I am trying to construct something sort of sum pyramid in my code, but I am not able to print anything after the end= ( in python 2.7)

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time

YEAR_STR= time.strftime('%Y')
MONTH_STR=time.strftime('%m')

num = 1
for i in range(0, 5):
    num = 1
    for j in range(0, i+1):
        print("(ABC_"+YEAR_STR+MONTH_STR+str(num), end="+")
        num = num + 1
    print()
```

The output I get is :

```
(ABC_2017031+
(ABC_2017031+(ABC_2017032+
(ABC_2017031+(ABC_2017032+(ABC_2017033+
(ABC_2017031+(ABC_2017032+(ABC_2017033+(ABC_2017034+
(ABC_2017031+(ABC_2017032+(ABC_2017033+(ABC_2017034+(ABC_2017035+
```

But the expected output is :

```
(ABC_2017031)/1
(ABC_2017031+ABC_2017032)/2
(ABC_2017031+ABC_2017032+ABC_2017033)/3
(ABC_2017031+ABC_2017032+ABC_2017033+ABC_2017034)4
```

and so on ....

I am not able to add the last **)/num** in the print statement. Can this be done?

Comment: how do you expect `(ABC_2017031)/1` when you put `print(...., end="+")` every time you are printing you are adding a `+` to the end of the print statement....

Comment: @MooingRawr you stole my rant. The OP does not seem to concatenate the `print` properly. It does not even contain the **)/num** he is looking for.

Comment: That was because after multiple trials nothing worked and i thought this was cleaner ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by yourself like this:

- you will concatenate the the output in a temporary variable
- you will be adding '+' only if it's not the last character in the line being printed

  ```
  import time

  YEAR_STR= time.strftime('%Y')
  MONTH_STR=time.strftime('%m')


  for i in range(0, 5):
    num = 0
    tmp = ""  
    for j in range(0, i+1):
      num = num + 1  
      tmp += "ABC_"+YEAR_STR+MONTH_STR+str(num)
      if (j < i):
        tmp+="+"

    print("(%s)/%d"% (tmp, num))
  ```

Output:

```
(ABC_2017031)/1
(ABC_2017031+ABC_2017032)/2
(ABC_2017031+ABC_2017032+ABC_2017033)/3
(ABC_2017031+ABC_2017032+ABC_2017033+ABC_2017034)/4
(ABC_2017031+ABC_2017032+ABC_2017033+ABC_2017034+ABC_2017035)/5
```

Comment: How to start this from 1 instead of 0? ( inside the brackets)

Comment: Instead of concatenating to a string with `+=`, why not put them all in a list and then use `'+'.join()`? That'd be much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The `end=` option actually just finalizes the string that way. You actually want something like this:

```
for i in range(5):
    print("+".join(["(ABC_"+YEAR_STR+MONTH_STR+")" for num in range(0, i+1)]), end="/{}\n".format(i+1))
```

Comment: But this is not printing the values incrementally inside the brackets. (ABC_201703)+(ABC_201703)+(ABC_201703)+(ABC_201703)+(ABC_201703)/5  and the brackets should be whole string enclosed divided by num